# How to construct a tuple with only one element for every object contained?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a tuple with multiple template class where only the template of the class change, as such:

```cpp
template<template<class> class T, class ...Ts>
class TriggerMap;

template<template<class> class T, class ...Ts>
class TriggerMap<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    public:
        TriggerMap(ThreadPool &_tp) : m_map(_tp) {}
        ~TriggerMap() = default;

    private:
        using TriggerMapImp = typename tuple_apply_template<T, Ts...>::type;
        TriggerMapImp m_tup;
};
```

with `tuple_apply_template`:

```cpp
template<class, class>
struct tuple_prepend;

template<class T, class ...Ts>
struct tuple_prepend<T, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
};

template<template<class> class T, class ...Ts>
struct tuple_apply_template;

template<template<class> class T, class _T, class ...Ts>
struct tuple_apply_template<T, _T, Ts...>
{
    using type = typename tuple_prepend<T<_T>, typename tuple_apply_template<T, Ts...>::type>::type;
};

template<template<class> class T, class _T>
struct tuple_apply_template<T, _T>
{
    using type = std::tuple<T<_T>>;
};
```

I would like to construct my object with an object reference in this case the object `ThreadPool`, how can I change the constructor of `TriggerMap` (that doesn't actually work) in an effiente way for run-time optimisation?

Comment: Related: [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) and/or [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: `TriggerMapImp` seems simply to be `std::tuple<T<Ts>...>`

Comment: I don't use syntax, because I have other behavior that doesn't when using `tuple_apply_template` that doesn't affect the given question.

Comment: Off-topic: `~TriggerMap() = default;` is bad, having any destructor prevents the move operations from being generated, meaning any time you move your object, it's silently copied instead.

Comment: Do you have any referency for this off-topic in the doc?

Comment: https://howardhinnant.github.io/smf.jpg

Comment: Please add `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications. In addition to that picture, it's easy to check: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qar9bo5Pv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the constructor compiling, I change it to:

```cpp
TriggerMap(ThreadPool &_tp) : m_map(T<Ts>(_tp)...) {}
```

Comment: If any body have the name of this type of syntax, let me know.

Comment: [Pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion)?

Comment: Yes, thank you!